# Google Sheets Query using Checkbox as search criteria

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I want to use a query in Google Sheets that lets me look at a column of checkboxes to filter on ones that are checked (TRUE).

```
=QUERY(Available!$A$3:$O, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O where O = '"& TEXT(TRUE) &"' and B > 100,000 order by B desc")
```

It is complaining of a literal value, but I am having a lot of trouble figuring out the proper syntax to ensure the query is reading the checkbox properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it like this:

```
=QUERY(Available!A3:O, 
 "where O = TRUE 
    and B > 100000 
  order by B desc")
```

if the range is **A:O** and you want all columns you don't need `select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O`

also `TRUE` is boolean so no need to treat it as `TEXT`

---

to fix ARRAY_LITERAL ERROR  you need to build your formula like:

```
={IFERROR(QUERY(Available!A2:O, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where M like '%(Blah)' order by B desc"), 
  {"1","","","","","","","","","","","",""}); 
  IFERROR(QUERY(Available!A2:O, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where C = 'BlehBleh' order by B desc limit 7"), 
  {"2","","","","","","","","","","","",""}); 
  IFERROR(QUERY(Available!A2:O, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where O = TRUE and B > 100000 order by B desc"), 
  {"3","","","","","","","","","","","",""})}
```

Comment: Still giving me the same error.  I am using it in a set of queries as such:  ={IFERROR(QUERY(Available!$A$3:$O, "where M like '%(Blah)' order by B desc"),"1");IFERROR(QUERY(Available!$A$3:$O, "where C = 'BlehBleh' order by B desc limit 7"),"2");IFERROR(QUERY(Available!$A$3:$O, "where O contains 'TRUE' and B > 100,000 order by B desc"),"3")}

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bXtXhYnZ3RRpsX6BBhPFBtvHlyWD9E5MNOfYkN39368/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Awesome!  That worked except for a small caveat.  Is it possible to look at column O as a query criteria?  Without actually populating O in the results column?  I updated the sheet to represent what I would want it to look like.

Comment: An alternative would be that the Available tab's column O (having the checkboxes) would also repeat the checkboxes in the results.  When I add the checkboxes to the results...it complains that the query results would override what is currently in that cell.

Comment: It looks right for the first and second query, but the third one is returning a "3" for the IFERROR function when the query should be matching something in the Available tab.  I can't see anything that would cause the query to not match row 5 or row 7.

Comment: `={IFERROR(QUERY(Available!A2:O, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where M like '%(Blah)' order by B desc"), {"1","","","","","","","","","","","",""});
  IFERROR(QUERY(Available!A2:O, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where C = 'BlehBleh' order by B desc limit 7"), {"2","","","","","","","","","","","",""});
  IFERROR(QUERY(Available!A2:O, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where O = TRUE and B > 100000 order by B desc"), {"3","","","","","","","","","","","",""})}`